Using Stripe in Angular with dynamic public keys
The docs for https://ngx-stripe.dev/docs/setup-application has a short section about using dynamic public keys, it refers to using the injectStripe method, and an example for it. However, the example is not do be found anywhere.
I've tried the following:
imports: [
...
     NgxStripeModule.forRoot(),
...
]

Notice no key in the module registration.
In my component I then:
constructor(...){
     injectStripe(environment.stripePublishableKey);
}

But I get this error as soon as I begin using any Stripe directive:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'elements')
    at StripeService.elements (ngx-stripe.mjs:435:28)
    at StripeElementsService.elements (ngx-stripe.mjs:689:43)
    at ngx-stripe.mjs:1407:63
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:27:1
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:2611:25)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:19:1
    at StripeCardGroupDirective.ngOnChanges (ngx-stripe.mjs:1410:30)


EDIT: This is the HTML
<div ngxStripeCardGroup class="card-container">
</div>


please share the html

@NarenMurali check edit now

It could be an issue with how the lifecycle works in Angular. Try by creating a variable and use the injectStripe. For example:
stripe = injectStripe(environment.stripePublishableKey);
